# Limit the result that I got from FBRequestConnection

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook iOS SDK to retrieve the data from Score.

Below are my codes...

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", mScore], @"score",
                                   nil];



[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%llu/scores", APP_ID] 
parameters: params HTTPMethod:@"GET" 
completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {}
```

I wanna ask how can I modify the params so that it will only return me a limited number of result? For example, I know I can do it with FQL by writing something like this LIMIT=20.
Since I'm not using FQL, how can I achieve the same thing with the above codes?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/) 
it should suffice

```
NSInteger limit = 3;
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%llu/scores?limit=%i", APP_ID, limit];
```

**EDIT**

Since the above seems not to work, have you tried passing the limit in the parameters?

```
NSInteger limit = 3;
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", mScore], @"score",
                                   limit, @"limit",
                                   nil];
```

**EDIT 2**

There's seems to be a problem with that API.

I tried the query

```
<APP_ID>/scores?limit=1
```

on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

and it's returning more than 1 result in any case.

Comment: Hmm I tried it but doesn't seems like working. 
I passed in 1 as the limit but it still return me with more than 1 result :(

Comment: Yea I did tried passing the limit in the params but still doesn't work. :(